# link viewcontroller variables to barplot view

Tags: uiview, xcode4.2, core-plot, viewcontroller

Im new with xcode I'm using XCode 4.2. I followed this tutorial
https://codejunkster.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/core-plot-2-bar-plot/
and when I run the app it only shows the graph that is in the tutorial and not my initial view... is there any way to set this graph(tutorial) as a UIView and resize it, so that it would be in a corner of the first View? (a small view inside a view)... To be more specific Im doing a single view application and in my first view I have labels, textfields and buttons, and when pressing a button the "small graph" will show the difference between the two variables

and also, how can I link the variables from this view controller to the graph... like if the users types a 5, the first bar will be at 5

Is there any tutorial online that show how to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Core Plot hosting view (`CPTGraphHostingView`) is a subclass of `UIView`—you position it like any other view. Don't add any subviews to the hosting view.

The view controller responsible for the graph can change any properties of the graph that it needs to. For example, it could change one or both plot ranges when it receives a message that the user took a certain action.

Comment: I'm sorry Erick, Im totally new with this... can you give me a code example of how to do the changes you say? thanks

Comment: It sounds like you need to find a basic iOS UI tutorial before you worry about integrating Core Plot into your app. StackOverflow is a good place to ask *specific* questions you might have. Look at all of the Core Plot example apps, including the Mac apps. They will show you various ways of setting up the UI and connecting buttons and other controls.